# Kendo UI DateTimePicker Getting Wrong Time Format ASP.NET C#

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, razor, kendo-ui, kendo-datetimepicker

I have some records in my database as below:
[image]

Note that the StartDateTime and EndDateTime are in 24 hours-system.
But when I display the datetime in my view, the time format is 12 hours-system as below:
[image]

From the html code, the value for "1st" End Date Time is correct, but in 12 hours-system:
[image]

The dates are used to calculate the amounts. This resulted in wrong number of hours calculated based on the kendoui datetimepicker. Can i know how to solve this?

Here is the JS:

```
$("#Payment_End_Date_" + count).kendoDateTimePicker({
                format: "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm",
                timeFormat: "HH:mm",
                interval: 60
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Change format to

```
format: "dd/MM/yyyy H:mm",
```